# Azure Runbook - GetAzurermlog

Tags: powershell, azure

I am unable to run the ‘Get-Azurermlog’ in Azure runbook.I get the error "The term 'Get-Azurermlog' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program". It a standard powershell cmdlet and works fine on my laptop PS console. Please advise.

```
   workflow Write-SB
  { 
$Cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name ‘Cre’
 Add-AzureAccount -Credential $Cred
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName “My subscription” 
InlineScript
  { 
 Get-Azurermlog }    
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install Azure Powershell.

You can follow the instructions here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/